# Django tag on template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-tagging

My code:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
  {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% block content %}
      <div class="content-section">
          <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <fieldset class="form-group">
                  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">
                      Create A Post
                  </legend>
                  {{ form|crispy }}
              </fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">
                      Post
                  </button>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    {% endblock content %}
{% else %}
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=/" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Restricted Access To Staff!</h1>
    <p>You will be redirected to the home page in 5 seconds</p>
  </body>
{% endif %}
```

The Error:
[image]

I can't figure out why it is not working, could it be something to do with the {% if request.user.is_staff %} bit?

Comment: `{% extends %}` should always be the *first* template tag, and thus does not allow to be moved inside an `{% if %} ... {% else %}` clause.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation on *template inheritance* says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance):

> If you use `{% extends %}` in a template, it must be the **first template tag** in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise.

You thus can not work with a [**`{% if … %} … {% else %} … {% endif %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#if) to determine whether or not to inherit.

You can move this logic to the view, so:

```
def some_view(request):
    # …
    if request.user.is_staff:
        return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'my_other_template.html', context)
```

It might be better to develop a decorator that will automatically check if the user is a staff member, and render content properly, something like:

```
from functools import wraps

def requires_staff_redirect(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def g(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            return render(request, 'my_other_template.html')
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return g
```

Then we can decorate a view like:

```
@requires_staff_redirect
def my_view(request):
    # …
```

and then it will only trigger the view if the user is a staff member, otherwise it will render the *`my_other_template.html`* page.

Comment: How would I do this with a class Template?